# Finding element by the second class in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Using inspect element, I have one element with two states:

`<span class="c-form-control-feedback c-form-control-feedback-error" title="" data-original-title="that username is already taken"></span>`

`<span class="c-form-control-feedback c-form-control-feedback-error" title=""></span>`

Sometimes the element has the first form, sometimes the last form. I need to find the element when it's in the first state, so I need a way to driver.find_element by the `data-original-title` class. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve them by checking whether contains the `data-original-title` attribute.

Selenium:

```
driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[contains(@data-original-title, '')]")
```

Beautifulsoup:

```
soup.find_all("span", attrs={"data-original-title": True})
```

---

Output:

```
[<span class="c-form-control-feedback c-form-control-feedback-error" data-original-title="that username is already taken" title=""></span>]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, is there any way to search the whole website by the 'that username is already taken'?